# Combining two record arrays

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I have two Numpy record arrays that have exactly the same fields. What is the easiest way to combine them into one (i.e. append one table on to the other)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `numpy.hstack()`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> desc = {'names': ('gender','age','weight'), 'formats': ('S1', 'f4', 'f4')} 
>>> a = numpy.array([('M',64.0,75.0),('F',25.0,60.0)], dtype=desc)
>>> numpy.hstack((a,a))
array([('M', 64.0, 75.0), ('F', 25.0, 60.0), ('M', 64.0, 75.0),
       ('F', 25.0, 60.0)], 
      dtype=[('gender', '|S1'), ('age', '<f4'), ('weight', '<f4')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in array1:
    array2.append(i)
```

Or (if implemented)

```
array1.extend(array2)
```

Now array1 contains also all elements of array2

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
desc = {'names': ('gender','age','weight'), 'formats': ('S1', 'f4', 'f4')} 
a = np.array([('M',64.0,75.0),('F',25.0,60.0)], dtype=desc)
b = np.array([('M',64.0,75.0),('F',25.0,60.0)], dtype=desc)
alen=a.shape[0]
blen=b.shape[0]
a.resize(alen+blen)
a[alen:]=b[:]
```

This works with structured arrays, though not recarrays. Perhaps this is a good reason to stick with structured arrays.

Comment: Is there a reason why this does not work with recarrays? I thought recarrays were just structured arrays with an extra __getattribute__/__setattr__ arguments?

Comment: I don't know why. I only know that when I try the same thing with recarrays I get a ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its own data.  Having run into problems like this with recarrays in the past, I tend to use structured arrays instead of recarrays. The syntactic sugar isn't worth the trouble.